# Generate anchor tag using Razor Pages

Tags: razor-pages

I'm familiar with the CRUD examples of how to generate an anchor link using `asp-page` and `asp-route-id`.

There are a lot of these examples but how do I construct an anchor tag that looks like this and is on a regular page that a visitor (and not an admin(CRUD)) would visit - for instance on a list-of-blog-posts-page:

```
<a href="/blog/my-first-blog-post">My first blog post</a>

<a href="/blog/my-second-blog-post">My first blog post</a>
```

I'm looking to use Razor syntax, and not by concatenating strings - something like this:

```
<a asp-page="blog/@{seoblogtitle}" asp-route-id="@model.id">@item.Title</a>
```

Where `@{seoblogtitle}` is a route template and `@model.id` is a GUID.

***TL;DR;***

How do you contruct an anchor link like the one below using Razor in a Razor Page?

```
<a href="/blog/my-first-blog-post">My first blog post</a>
```

Comment: If you want to create custom taghelper you can see the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: That's not what I'm after actually. I want to use built-in framework functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are after. You mention a Guid, but you don't feature it in the generated URL. I am working on the assumption that you need to pass the Guid along with the seo-friendly title. What you can do is construct a `Dictionary<string, string>` and pass that to the `asp-all-route-values` attribute of the Anchor tag helper.

Your Blog page has this template: `@page "{title}/{id}"`

Your model includes a `List<BlogTitle>` property (`Links`) where the `BlogTitle` class looks like this (at a minimum):

```
public class BlogLink
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

In the content page, you would do this:

```
@foreach(var link in Model.Links)
{
    var routeValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "title", SeoFriendly(link.Title) },
        { "id", link.Id.ToString() }
    };
    <a asp-page="blog" asp-all-route-data="routeValues">@link.Title</a><br />
}
```

The SeoFriendly method is used to convert "My First Blog Title" etc to its seo-friendly version. It could even be defined in a `@functions` section in the page:

```
@functions{
    public static string SeoFriendly(string s)
    {
        return s.Replace(" ", "-").ToLower(); // you need something more robust than this
    }
}
```

See Note 1 here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/anchor-tag-helper

Note: if you want to keep the dictionary generation code out of the content page, add a `Dictionary<string, string>` property to your `BlogTitle` class and generate the values in the PageModel.